# how to inject code with a batch into a batch that has existing code

Tags: python, html, batch-file, helper

do I convert it a txt file? how do I inject the new line in between the other lines? I'm trying to inject a wallet address to a simple mining batch file without needing to physically open it prior.

pretty much the last step to automating my mining rigs for full self sufficiency.

if anyone has any way of doing this, please describe in full detail or show an example, as I am self taught and in way over my head for a project that's exceeding expectations before release lol

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a settings file, and if that file doesn't exist, say on the first run, to create it instead:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not exist example_settings.cmd (
    echo Creating settings file
    rem Prepare a helper batch file to store the settings
    echo|set /p="set _key=">example_settings.cmd

    rem Imagine this "echo Example" is instead a command that returns a new value
    echo Example>>example_settings.cmd
)

call example_settings.cmd
echo The setting is %_key%
```

This will create a settings file with the key set, and on subsequent runs, use that key from the helper batch file instead of trying to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would read in the entire file with f.readlines() so you get a list of strings (where each string represents a line in the file), write some logic that determines where the new string should go in between, and then re-write that to a file after.